# Java Combination Lock

Tags: java

So, the purpose of the program is to create a 3 digit combination lock (with integers between 0 and 39) that will update the current position(that starts at 0) of the dial to the right, then left, then right, and then left.If all of the positions are found true, then the ComboLock will unlock. The problem with my code is that when I run the program and input the correct number of ticks to the right to change the value of the first position, it just says that the combination is wrong instead of prompting me to position 2. Here is my code for my ComboLock class thus far:

```
public class ComboLock
{

private int currentNumber = 0; //current value lock dial is set to

 private int secret1, secret2, secret3; 
 private boolean pos0 = true; 
 private boolean pos1, pos2, pos3 = false; 
 private boolean unlock = false; 

public ComboLock(int secret1, int secret2, int secret3)
{
 this.secret1 = secret1;
 this.secret2 = secret2;
 this.secret3 = secret3; 
}
/**
  Resets the state of the lock so that it can be opened again.
*/

 public void reset()
 {
  pos0 = true; 
  pos1= false; 
  pos2 = false; 
  pos3 = false; 
  }


 public void turnLeft(int ticks)
 {
    if(pos1 == true)
     {
       currentNumber += ticks; 
       if(currentNumber == secret2)
       {
           pos2 = true; 
        }
        else
        {
            pos2 = false; 
        }

    }


 }

 public void turnRight(int ticks)
  {
    if(pos0)
   {
      currentNumber = (40 - ticks); 

        if(currentNumber == secret1)
     {
         pos1 = true; 
     }
    }
     else
     {
       if(currentNumber - ticks > 0)
       {
       pos3 = true; 
      }
      else
      {
          currentNumber = (40 - (ticks - currentNumber)); 
          pos3 = false; 
          if(currentNumber == secret3)
          {
              pos3 = true; 
            }
        }

    }

}

 public boolean open()
  {
  if(pos1 && pos2 && pos3)
  {
      unlock = true; 
      System.out.println("Click!"); 
    }
  else
  {
      unlock = false; 
      System.out.println("Wrong! Lets try again.");   
    }
    return unlock; 
}

public int getCurrentNumber()
{
   return currentNumber;
 }

}
```

Comment: Aside: Don't use `if (pos1 == true)`, just use `if (pos1)`

Comment: Have you tried debugging this code in Eclipse? It would be a great learning opportunity. Stackoverflow is a great site for technical questions. It is not a great site for having other people do your homework for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design aside, just a couple of minor errors.

When you turn left, you cannot simply add the `ticks` to your `currentNumber` because the number can only between `0-39` but your code allows for greater than `39`. So you need to use the modulus operator `%` to wrap around 40 numbers.

In `turnLeft`

```
//          currentNumber += ticks;
            // Should be
            currentNumber = (currentNumber + ticks)%40;
```

Next problem is you never move on from `pos0` when turning right and so in your code, you never move to the `else` part of the `turnRight` method.

```
public void turnRight(int ticks) {
    // ... your code ... //
        if (currentNumber == secret1) {
            pos1 = true;
            pos0 = false; // Add this
        }
    } // ... your code ... //
}
```

EDIT: That should fix your problem. But code is rather hard to maintain especially if you start to increase the size of the combination lock. To fix this and to address problem mentioned by jchamp, I have completely refactored the class to be shorter and more flexible I think:

```
public class ComboLock {

    private static final int MAX_NUMBERS = 40;

    private int currentNumber = 0; // current value lock dial is set to
    private int combination[] = null; // holds the combination to the lock
    private int currentPosition = 0; // current position of the combination array used for comparison

    // Allow for a lock that can handle more than size 3
    public ComboLock(int ... combination) {
        this.combination = combination;
    }

    /**
     * Resets the state of the lock so that it can be opened again.
     */
    public void reset() {
        currentPosition = 0;
    }

    public void turnLeft(int ticks) {
        currentNumber = (currentNumber + ticks) % MAX_NUMBERS;
        // Only compare the number when turning left the current position is odd
        if (currentPosition%2 == 1 && combination[currentPosition] == currentNumber) {
            currentPosition = Math.min(currentPosition + 1, combination.length - 1);
        }
    }

    public void turnRight(int ticks) {
        currentNumber = (currentNumber + (MAX_NUMBERS - ticks % MAX_NUMBERS)) % MAX_NUMBERS;
        // Only compare the number when turning right and the current position is even
        if (currentPosition%2 == 0 && combination[currentPosition] == currentNumber) {
            currentPosition = Math.min(currentPosition + 1, combination.length - 1);
        }
    }

    public boolean open() {
        return combination[currentPosition] == combination[combination.length - 1];
    }

    public int getCurrentNumber() {
        return currentNumber;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComboLock combo = new ComboLock(39, 25, 35);
        combo.turnRight(1);
        combo.turnLeft(26);
        combo.turnRight(30);
        assert combo.open();
        combo = new ComboLock(39, 25, 35);
        combo.turnLeft(39);
        combo.turnRight(14);
        combo.turnLeft(40);
        assert !combo.open();
    }
}
```